# Convert a member of a structure of type char * to java.lang.Object in Java using SWIG

Tags: java, swig

I’m trying to convert a member of a structure of type char * to java.lang.Object in Java generated class. I want to do that because I want to pass to it objects of type Integer and String. Is it possible to do that?

For example I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct Foo
{
    int type;
    char * data;
} Foo;
```

The `type` member is for determining the data type of the `data` member - Integer or String.

In the generated Java class of the Foo structure I want to have a set method (for the `data` member) on which I can pass arguments of type String and Integer. I can convert the String and Integer objects to some convenient data type for example byte[] before I pass them to the set method. I want only set method not get method. Then in the C code I have to use the passed Integer or String value according to the `type` member.

Comment: Can you show us some code on why you need to do that and what you have tried so far? And why do you want to convert it to `Object` and not - for instance - `byte[]`? From the byte array you could then easily change to `String` and `int`.

Comment: If I use byte[] in Java I'll have to add data length member in the structure for the length of the byte array. Am I wrong? Can you give me an example of your solution?

Comment: I don't know anything about where how you get your data etc, so I can not tell you anything until you provide us with more code (maybe also on the java side). Also: How would this problem (length of the array) change by changing it to an Object?

Comment: I am sorry about the brief information. I've updated my question.

Comment: `Object` doesn't make much sense. What do you want it to do when you're given an unknown type which is neither an `Integer` nor a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to directly do what you're asked for. That's because in Java you cannot cast a java.lang.Object to int or Integer or String.

That said, what you likely need to do is pass byte array to Java, and in the Java world implement some "deserialization" function, which - depending on the type field - produces either an int or a String from that byte array.

The actual implications of passing a byte array via JNI I don't know. But I suppose that should be left to a different question.